# Check for duplicates before inserting

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

Before inserting into the database, I'm using the following code to check for duplicates. To me, a duplicate is only considered a duplicate when `name`, `description`, `price`, `city`, and `enddate` match.

```
foreach($states_to_add as $item) {
    $dupesql = "SELECT 
                    COUNT(*) 
                FROM 
                    table 
                WHERE 
                    (   
                        name = '$name' 
                        AND description = '$description' 
                        AND manufacturer = '$manufacturer' 
                        AND city ='$city' 
                        AND price = '$price' 
                        AND enddate = '$end_date'
                    )";

    $duperaw = mysql_query($dupesql);

    if($duperaw > 0) {
        echo nl2br("$name already exists in $city \n");
    } 
    else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO table (..... (here go the values to be inserted)
        ....
```

Each value is defined prior to running through this checking, my result always comes back as item already exists.  I dumped "dupesql" and copy/pasted the command into phpmyadmin which comes back with count 0.

Comment: An INSERT from elsewhere could happen between your SELECT and your INSERT, then you'd have broken data. Don't do the uniqueness checking yourself, add a UNIQUE constraint inside the database and ignore the expected "unique constraint violation" errors.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You want to do the following:

```
$dupesql = "SELECT * FROM table where (name = '$name' AND description = '$description' AND manufacturer = '$manufacturer' AND city ='$city' AND price = '$price' AND enddate = '$end_date')";

$duperaw = mysql_query($dupesql);

if (mysql_num_rows($duperaw) > 0) {
  //your code ...
}
```

See [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) for more information.

Comment: You did typo mistake sir..

if (mysql_num_rows($duberaw) > 0) {

Answer (score 6):

As I see it your question can be broken down into 2 parts. Why is my PHP code not working? I don't know, don't know much PHP and other people seem to have just answered that :-). The second question is how can I check for duplicates? You're checking for duplicates the completely wrong way.

Create a [unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) / [primary key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) on your table. Then when you try to insert the DB will throw an error if there's a duplicate. Catch the error and deal with it how you want. Counting the number of records is definitely the wrong way to go and will be a significant detriment to the speed of your code.

Comment: Im reading up on this as I move forward with this project and more data gets filled in, I'm not 100% sure (yet) how to go about specifying the unique index/primary key based on all the values I've described (name, description, price, city, enddate).

Comment: @Mike, I included links to the official MySQL site, which should give you some help. Thinking about it and looking over the answers you don't actually need to get your PHP code to work. If you try the insert and catch the exception then the rest of the code doesn't need to be there...

Comment: Thanks! I'm reading up on that.  For the time being though, using if count > 0 seems to work. I'm concerned about future expansion and having to change the parameters of the primary key as I add more filters to check against.

Answer (score 1):

You can still run into race conditions where 2 users try to insert dups at the same time, checking for dups using a select statement simultaneously gives both users the go ahead to insert their records.  I prefer to set unique index on the DB and then catch the error that bubbles up from the DB.

Comment: its not multiple users adding info into the db, it would be 1 person parsing a new feed once or twice per day.  performance isn't a huge concern on this for that very reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
foreach($states_to_add as $item) {
    $dupesql = "SELECT 
                    name 
                FROM 
                    table 
                WHERE 
                    (name = '$name' 
                        AND description = '$description' 
                        AND manufacturer = '$manufacturer' 
                        AND city ='$city'
                        AND price = '$price' 
                        AND enddate = '$end_date'
                    )";

    $duperaw = mysql_query($dupesql);

    if( mysql_num_rows($duperaw) ) {
        echo nl2br("$name already exists in $city \n");
    } 
    else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO table (..... (here go the values to be inserted)
```

Comment: If you leave the COUNT(*) there will always be a row, thus the problem hasn't been resolved.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to change `COUNT(*)` to `name` or `*`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check for uniqueness in PHP, you can just do the whole test in MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (name, description, ......)
  SELECT name1, description1, manufacturer1, city1, price1, enddate1
  FROM (SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT 
      @name:= '$name' as name1
      ,@description:= '$description' as description1
      ,.....
    FROM DUAL as d1
    LEFT JOIN table1 t1 
           ON (t1.name = d1.name1 
          AND t1.description = d1.description1
          AND ......)
    WHERE t1.name IS NULL) s1) s2
```

This will only insert the values if they pass the uniqueness test.

Comment: I'm inserting about 20-30 values on each one, and from my standpoint right this second, this might get fairly confusing, though i'm most likely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In short you need to do your checking through PHP and you also need to add a composite unique constraint in your MySQL table to get the best of both worlds.

it would be good if we broke down your question into two separate questions.

1- How do I check duplicates using PHP and notify about the user before executing query?
2- How do I specify a composite unique constraint in MySQL?

First, you need a simple PHP function to check whether this record exist in the DB or not, like the one below:

```
function is_exist($table, $data){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `" . $table . "` WHERE ";

    foreach ($data as $key => $val) :
    $sql .= "`$key`='" . $val . "' AND ";
    endforeach;

    $sql = substr($sql,0, -5);

    $result = $mysql_query($sql);
    $count = $mysql_num_rows($result);

    return ($count > 0) ? true: false;
}
```

You should call your PHP function like this way below:

```
    $data = array('column1'=>$_POST['value'],'column2'=>$_POST['value'], ...);

    if(is_exist($data)){
      // Print your error message
    }else{
     // Run your insert query
    }
```

This way you can prevent duplicates before going to the MySql Database, but in order to have a duplicate free database, you need to add a composite unique constraint in your MySQL table.

This simple SQL command can do the trick:

```
alter table `tablename` add unique index(name, description, manufacturer, city, price, enddate);
```

I hope that helps, if I mess anything please burden me.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following

```
  INSERT IGNORE INTO person_tbl (last_name, first_name) 
  -> VALUES( 'Jay', 'Thomas');
```