# Check if this is duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check if the `username` already exists and throw an error message if exist, any tips how can I do it?
I've already tried to search but only found `mysql_errno` but it won't work for me.

```
  if ($valid) {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        //$password = md5($password);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,password,role) values(?, ?, ?)";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($username,$password,$role));
        Database::disconnect();
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
```

sd

Comment: You should first run a `SELECT` to check if the username exists then, if not, run your `INSERT`.

Comment: But after the `SELECT username FROM users` what should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check for duplicates before inserting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719039/check-for-duplicates-before-inserting)

Comment: @AndréMiguel, I think you should go through these tutorials first. `www.mysqltutorial.org` or `https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/

`

Comment: @Shibon `mysql_` function is no longer used...

Comment: If select count(username) from users wher username =@ > =1 then display a msg and call it an error or create a unique constrain and catch the error with a handler

Comment: @AndréMiguel try to user the logic from that link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if the `username` is already used :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username
```

If you return one row : **you throw your error**, else you do your `INSERT`

So your code should look like this :

```
if ($valid) {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql_check = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username";
    $test = $pdo->prepare($sql_check);
    $test->bindParam(':username', $username); 
    $test->execute;
```

Now here is two solution to check if you have one row :

```
    if($test->rowCount() > 0) {
        // error
    }
```

or

```
    $user = $test->fetch();

    if (!empty($user)) {
        // error
    }
```

And now if you don't have error, do you insert :

```
    else {
        //$password = md5($password);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,password,role) values(?, ?, ?)";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($username,$password,$role));
        Database::disconnect();
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: But how can I check the returned row?

Comment: @AndréMiguel with -`>fetch`

Comment: And to display the error i just need to `echo` some error message right? or I'm missing something else?

Comment: I don't know your code, but you can use echo, display some flash message, if it's an ajax call you can return an error message and display it using js...you just show us the request part, no idea how your project looks !

Comment: It gives me this error now `Notice: Undefined property: PDOStatement::$execute in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestao\Colaboradores\create_user.php on line 68`

Comment: I'm not using ajax, do I could use an `echo<script> alert` right ?

Comment: What did you use line 68 ? And yes you can try an echo to display some error message if the form is in the same page

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

You could make the username field unique, this way, MYSQL would throw an error if you try to insert a line with an existing username.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,password,role) values(?, ?, ?)";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$result = $q->execute(array($username,$password,$role));
if(!$result) {
    // print out your error message
}
```

Otherwise, make a select with the wanted username and see if a row is returned (= already used) or not (=available).

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($username));
$result = $q->fetchAll();
// test result, if 1 > print error, etc
```

Comment: I've already that field as ´UNIQUE´ but I want to display an error message on the php page, and not the usual error message from MySQL

Comment: @AndréMiguel `execute` return true or false if the query was successful or not, you can make a condition on it to display your own error message

Comment: And i've tried this `$sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM users WHERE username = ?";
   $q2 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
   $q2->execute(array($username));
   $result = $q2->fetchAll();
   if ($result >1){
    echo '<h2>ERROR</h2>';
   }
   else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,password,role) values(?, ?, ?)";
   $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $q->execute(array($username,$password,$role));
   }`    but it skips the error message

Comment: does result contain directly the count ? (hint: print_r it to see the content)

Comment: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [count] => 1 [0] => 1 ) )`

Comment: Then test $result[0]['count'] ^^'

Comment: Don't execute the insert query if there's already an existing row dude ^^

Comment: I'm not executing it, it's on `else` so it shouldn't be any existing row

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $username
```

If found show error, else insert

Answer (score -2):

```
 <?php
     $getUniqueUsername=$con->query("select * from user where name='$user_name");
     $rowCount=$getUniqueUsername->num_rows;

     if($rowCount) {          
          $insertQuery=$con->query("insert into table_name (field_name) Values('".$values."'));
     }
?>
```

Comment: this is open to SQL injection

Comment: also, code only answers aren't answer IMO -- add explanation so OP/future readers can understand the solution/problem at hand