# PHP MYSQL display error message on duplicate entries

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code to validate if an entry is duplicated or not, but instead of showing the error it just skips to `index.php` and I need it to show the error message.. can someone help me out please?

```
if ($valid) {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //$password = md5($password);

    $sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    $q2 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
    $q2->execute(array($username));
    $result = $q2->fetchAll();
    if ($result >1){
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("user already exists")';
        echo '</script>';
    }else{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,password,role) values(?, ?, ?)";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($username,$password,$role));
    }
    Database::disconnect();
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: `$result` is an array so `if ($result >1){` makes no real sense, see @Masivuyecokile answer

Comment: As you are using `count()` in your SQL, it will always return 1 row.  Debug using `print_r($result);` (or similar)

Comment: [Didn't you ask this already?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53866992/1415724) and accepted an answer. This IMHO is a repost.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner It's a repost.. If I knew should't have answered

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile No worries :)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner not rlly, po crlh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
if ($result >1){}
```

TO

```
if (count($result) > 0){}
```

`$result` is an array so use `count()` to count array elements.

Edit.

Instead of :  $sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM users WHERE username = ?";

You could

```
$sql2 = "SELECT userID,firstname,lastname FROM users WHERE username = ?";
```

Comment: Oh okay i got that! But it keeps skiping the error message and lead to index.php :/

Comment: check the edit @AndréMiguel

Comment: Still the same... I bet it's something else that's causing this problem...

Comment: comment out this line `header("Location: index.php");` then its gonna work, this line is outside of the if

Comment: But if it is an sucess insert I will need to redirect the user to the index.php

Comment: Put it inside the success then

Comment: I've move it inside the `insert` if and it worked, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: And by the way if I had more than 1 field I would need to verify how could I do that?

Comment: I don't think I understand

Comment: Let's say that I have to filter to be unique not only the username as we just did but also the email and phone number, should I use an multiple `WHERE` query and the remain code will be the same?

Comment: Yes will be the same you just add more and email = ? and number = ? then add on your execute

Comment: Yea i've tried it but it gives the error to all the fields even if just one of them is duplicated